# PHP: How to replace quotes

Tags: php

I am using this but it is not working:

```
$replaced = str_replace(''', '"', $text);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: don't try to do this for data, you try to input into a database. use prepared statements or the *_real_escape_string of your database system

Comment: why do you need such a replace?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
$replaced = str_replace('\'', '"', $text);
```

OR

```
$replaced = str_replace("'", '"', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$replaced = str_replace('\'', '"', $text);`

Answer (score -3):

```
str_replace(array(" ' ", " \" ", " &quot; "), " ", htmlspecialchars($variable ) );
```